# Limiting scrolling to DIV

Tags: javascript, html, scrollbar

This has been an annoyance I've come across a few times so I thought it best to see if there is a good way around it.  I have many instances of "scrollable" DIV elements in various places which work almost exactly as intended, with the exception of when a Mouse wheel or track pad is what is controlling the scroll.

The main issue is that once the div reaches the bottom of its scroll bar the command is then transferred over to the main scroll bar, annoyingly changing the users page position.  I notice that the same thing happens with the "Questions that may already have your answer" box at the top of this page, so too does the box that I'm currently typing in which makes me think it is something that happens as standard, however I'm sure I have used web sites in the past that have required me to move my cursor outside of an element in order to scroll the main page.

Is there a way to overcome this?  I'm happy to use Javascript if that is the best solution, my initial thoughts were that some kind of onmouseover command could lock the screen until a onmouseout occurred but my JS is very limited and I couldn't find anything similar to adapt.

An example of a DIV element that I'm using is:

```
<div id='bodytext' 
style='width:300px; height:300px; z-index:4; visibility: visible; overflow: auto;'>
Data more than 300px high
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for any help, and if it's not possible then clarification would still be very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to look in to the [DOM scroll event](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/scroll.html) and determine what element is currently being scrolled. Essentially once you're able to determine that the event is occurring on the parent element you'll want to [stop the event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.stopPropagation).

Comment: Thank you, I've read up on your links and can understand the concept.  I'll leave as unanswered for now in case anyone is able to come up with anything I understand better, otherwise I'll see if I can get it working and accept your answer tomorrow.

Comment: I thought there would be a much easier solution to this, testing small scale worked perfectly but it was causing me problems (or I was causing myself problems) implementing it into dynamically generated content.  That said, this is an accurate answer to the question I posed so the answer has been accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You can listen to wheel events on the scrollable target element and prevent the default behavior only if the 'end of the scroll' has been reached.

```
var el = document.getElementById("Element");
var wrapper = document.getElementById("Wrapper");
wrapper.addEventListener("wheel", wheelEvent);

function wheelEvent(e){
  var space = (wrapper.scrollHeight - wrapper.offsetHeight) - wrapper.scrollTop;
    if(e.deltaY < 0){
    if(wrapper.scrollTop == 0){
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
  }else if(space <= 0){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
}
```

Here is a working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/rivieremanuel/rcxa6csr/4/

Comment: Very nice!  This is very similar to what I ended up writing, although admittedly this is much tidier.

Comment: Thanks @JoeP, glad you like it.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using jquery you could do something like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#bodytext').on('mouseenter', function()
  {
    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
  });
  $('#bodytext').on('mouseleave', function()
  {
    $('body').css('overflow', 'visible');
  });
});
```

This will automatically hide the scrollbar of the body when you enter the box and add it when you leave it.

Comment: Down-voted for answering with a framework on a non-framework question. Revise your answer and reply and I'll be happy to retract my vote.